# center align the toolbar items when height of toolbar is changed

Tags: android, alignment, toolbar

i am trying to reduce the height of toolbar but when i have declared particular height items inside toolbar doesn't formatted centered.how to arrange them centered in my case.Below are my complete details

[image]

Toolbar.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#414e5b"

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Themes.xml

```
    <style name="Orange" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ----------------
            <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/ActionButtonStyle</item>
    ------------------

        </style>

<style name="ActionButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:minWidth">0dip</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">40dip</item> 
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">0dip</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below xml code to create your `Toolbar`. Which gives you to get your Toolbar at `centre` position :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="#414e5b"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
```